# Best practices of Exception handling in ASP.NET web applications

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

We are working on exception handling with ASP.NET web applications (with C# language). Would you please let me know the best practices of Exception handling?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/709072/methods-to-handle-exceptions-in-a-web-project-using-c

Answer (score 6):

One thing you might want to look at is [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/). Other than that [the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w16865z6.aspx) is a good place to start.

Comment: Yes, Elmah + a custom errors page (`<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="AppErrors.aspx">`) + don't have empty `catch` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Application_Error function in Global.asax to catch and handle all exception errors in your ASP.NET application.

Check this Microsoft Help article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306355 and scroll to where it says "How to use the Application_Error method".

Answer (score 0):

Look at MS Enterprise Library and [The Exception Handling Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203116.aspx) too.